# Simulate keys or switch keys and send to active window with Python

Tags: python, keyboard, keylistener, sendkeys

One of my keys is not working, even after having exchanged the keyboard.

I use a German keyboard, the key affected is mapped to the characters ?, ß and . Typing is really annoying when having to copy-paste the characters in every text/email. Re-assigning the keys with e.g. Sharp Keys did not work out and I don't wan't to write into the registry manually.

I was thinking of writing a script (preferably with Python) which, when I press the key right next to the broken one (in my case mapped to ´´) sends ß,? or \ (the latter two when pressed in combination with shift and alt, respectively) to the active window (browser, text editor ...) instead.

Comment: I'd try to figure out the problem with the keyboard first (superuser.com would be a good place to start).

Comment: The keyboard has been exchangend and looked after twice. Have no money for further repairs.

Comment: I should have been clearer; the *keyboard* is clearly not the problem if a completely separate keyboard exhibits the same problem.  There is an issue with the computer, most likely with the operating system configuration since I can't even imagine a USB hardware issue that would be confined to a particular key on a keyboard.

Comment: Worked my way around it today with Autohotkey.